# Why is mysql giving error while creating function?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a function that receives a code associated with a bus as a parameter and returns the number of stops the bus has in a route.

My code is the following:

```
create function num_paragem(bus_code int) 
returns int

Begin
    Declare x int default 0;
    select count(code_stop) into x from Bus_Stops where cod_bus = code;
end;
```

I keep getting these errors:

`syntax error, unexpected END_OF_INPUT, expecting ';'` -> it happens when I declare the variable x.

`syntax error, unexpected END` -> it occurs in the last line of the code.

Can someone please help me find the mistake on my function definition?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You run into the delimiter problem: We need to tell the parser the delimiters **inside** the function as well as the delimiter of **the function definition**.

Try this;

```
-- set special delimiter
DELIMITER $$

create function num_paragem(bus_code int) 
returns int
Begin
    Declare x int default 0; -- delimiter inside the function
    select count(code_stop) into x from Bus_Stops where cod_bus = code;
end;

-- delimiter of the function definition
$$

-- set delimiter back to normal
DELIMITER ;
```